# Can we print on console through struts config file?

Tags: java, struts

I am trying to locally set up a struts 1.0 project. In struts config, the code has initialization plug in to read .ini file which has some if conditions. Its giving error that a variable is not defined. Is there any way we can print on console in which if condition it is going? I cannot make change in the servlet class, its code is not accessible to me.

Comment: Why do you want to print to console? Struts is a framework for web applications.

Comment: I want to print anywhere inside the logs file(may be), Its not going to the starting webpage. When I am publishing to server.. it is giving error.

Comment: Post your error on your post so that we can help you.

Comment: This whole thing is resolved.. Thanks for the time.. I am able to set up the workspace.. I have another question.. Please answer if u know: I want to have quotes in c:out value. How can I do this?

Comment: c:out value ='&quot;ABc&quot;' not working

Comment: That's another SO question, please create a new question so that we can assist you.

Comment: I have created.. Please help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425246/write-string-with-quotes-in-cout-vaue