# Write string with quotes in c:out vaue?

Tags: string, jsp, jstl, quotes

I want to write a string with quotes in a jsp page which is using jstl tag c:out for its value that means I want to write:
c:out value = '"4"'
Please suggest asap..

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to use escapeXml attribute?

`<c:out value='"4"' escapeXml="false"></c:out>`

Comment: I tried this but it was not working. Even &quot; and escaping with \ is not working. I am facing same issue for \ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<c:out value='\\"4\\"'/>
```

Comment: Not working. Actually <c:out itself is inside quotes. I am passing this to a javascript function.